# Реализация двух языков PHP

Tags: php, интернационализация

Есть двуязычный сайт с использованием .ini файлов.

Всё работает хорошо, но возник вопрос, как сохранить язык при переходе по ссылке на другую страницу.

Вот сам код:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['lang_site'])){
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang_site'];
}else{
    $lang = 'en';
}
if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
    // задаем язык сайту
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    setcookie ("lang_site", $lang, time() + 3600*24, "/"); 
}
$listDataIni = parse_ini_file($lang.".ini"); // получаем данные из ini-файла
?>
```

Вот пример ссылки:

```
<a href="faq.php"><?= $listDataIni[faq]; ?></a>
```

Я так понимаю, что к самой ссылке нужно приписать значение переменной, но не могу понять как.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="faq.php?lang=<?= $lang ?>"><?= $listDataIni[faq]; ?></a>
```

Рекомендую добавить в код условие "Или":

```
if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
// задаем язык сайту
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
setcookie ("lang_site", $lang, time() + 3600*24, "/"); }
else{
$lang = 'en';
setcookie ("lang_site", $lang, time() + 3600*24, "/");
}
```

Comment: Rikaz, нужно, что бы lang приравнивался к текущему выбранному языку, а не к конкретному.